# Have an HTML Entity Sit Above Text Whilst Keeping the Normal Document Flow

Tags: html, css, html-entities

I have a blockquote with an html quotation mark that I'd like to sit above some text.

The problem I have is when I make the quote mark large it generates a load of whitespace. I've set the line-height to 0, but that doesn't seem to work.

How do i have an HTML entity (the quote mark) above the text but have the natural element flow below it?

codepen: https://codepen.io/emilychews/pen/XvEvqY

Many thanks in advance for any help

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;

  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.quote-wrapper {
  width: 50%;
  background: lightgray;
}

aside.quote-mobile {
  background: lightblue;
}

.quote-mark {
  line-height: 0;
  font-size: 7.159rem;
  margin-top: 4rem;
  padding: .5rem 0 0 .5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="quote-wrapper">
  <aside class="quote-mobile">
    <p class="quote-mark">&#8223;</p>
    <blockquote class="fees-pull-quote">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat
    </blockquote>
  </aside>
</div>
```

Comment: Try `margin-bottom:unset;` for `.quote-mark` class

Comment: https://codepen.io/ntamil/pen/MNGWze

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might need a bit more design for your likings, but this works:

```css
blockquote {
  padding: 5%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: justify;
}

blockquote:before,
blockquote:after {
  font-size: 7.5rem;
  position: fixed;
  opacity: 0.2;
}

blockquote:before {
  content: '\201C';
  left: 0;
  top: -2%;
}

blockquote:after {
  content: '\201D';
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<blockquote>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat
</blockquote>
```